# How do you write UI tests for a command line app in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-ui-testing

I'm making a small Zork-type game, and I don't want to have to type my way through the whole thing to test the game play every time I change something. Is there a way to use UI testing to do it for me?

I've tried looking around, but everyone just talks about running UI tests *from* the command line. But, I'd like to know how to do it *for* a console app.

Comment: You don't. End of story.

Comment: No sense of fun, @clause?

Comment: UI testing is for testing your own UI. You might be able to rig up some Applescript to do this; or you could possibly write your own shell script test driver. Better would be designing the code such that you can start from whatever state you need; then you don't have to run through all the preceding steps.

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know what your codebase looks like, but your best bet is probably to create test files that run the logic you want to test. You may want to make all logic input independent so that input can be passed by either your tests or a user.